# MongoDB update nested object dependent on json input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have json data that is structured in the following form:

```
[
{"size":100,"year":2015,"geography":"London","age":"21","gender":"Female"},
{"size":80,"year":2015,"geography":"Cardiff","age":"38","gender":"Male"},
{"size":80,"year":2013,"geography":"Edinburgh","age":"36","gender":"All"}
]
```

And I am trying to add it to a database collection with the following schema:

```
const Schema = new Schema({
  geography: String,
  size: {
    2013: {
      male: { 
        age: {

        }
      } 
      female: {
        age: {

        }
      }
      all: {
        age: {

        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I'm currently trying to set up my update to work in the following way:

```
query = { geography : geography};
update = { geography : geography, $set: { "year.gender.age" : size}

Schema.updateOne( query, update, { upsert: true };
```

The $set here obviously does not work as the update does not know to pull the values from the json data. I have tried making year, gender and age variables and then refactoring the set (see below) but this does not work either.

```
$set: { `${year}.${gender{.$age}` }
```

So the question is how can I use the values in my JSON data to determine which embedded field to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better option here would be a different schema which is not dynamic, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52383596/122005).

Nonetheless, if you are to go with the current schema, you can map the values in the JSON as follows:

For example, if you have an object like

```
const obj = {
    "size": 100,
    "year": 2015,
    "geography": "London",
    "age": "21",
    "gender": "Female"
}
```

to transform it to an update object of the form

```
{
    "geography": "London",
    "2015.female.21": 100
}
```

requires the following map:

```js
const obj = {
    "size": 100,
    "year": 2015,
    "geography": "London",
    "age": "21",
    "gender": "Female"
}

const doc = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr === "geography") {
        acc["geography"] = obj[curr];
        return acc;
    };

    switch(curr) {
        case "year":
        case "gender":
        case "age":
            acc[`${obj['year']}.${obj['gender'].toLowerCase()}.${obj['age']}`] = obj['size']

    }
    return acc;

}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, null, 4));
```

which you can then use in your update operation as

```
Model.updateOne( query, { '$set': doc }, { upsert: true }, callback );
```

Comment: Thank you. I think you are correct that the most sensible solution in this instance is to modify the schema. Nonetheless, thanks for providing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in order to create object like this-
`{"size":100,"year":2015,"geography":"London","age":"21","gender":"Female"}`

I think you need to set your schema to:

```js
const Schema = new Schema({
  geography: String,
  size: Number,
  year,: String,
  gender: String,
  age: String
});
```

Then to update use something like:

```js
update = { {$and: [{year:"2015"}, {age:"33"} /*and more*/]}, $set: { size : size}
```